# Spring 3.2 AOP - Intercepting methods by annotation

Tags: spring, annotations, aop

I'm trying to intercept any method tagged w/ a custom annotation and the reason you read this is because I can't get it to work. I've been following simple examples but can't get it to work.

Here is my code.

**MyAnnotation.java:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  String value() default "";
  String key() default "";
  String condition() default "";
}
```

**MyAspect.java:**

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  @Pointcut(value="execution(public * *(..))")
  public void anyPublicMethod() { }

  @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(myAnnotation)")
  public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("In AOP process");
    return 5; //jointPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

**spring-config.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
           xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">


    ...

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/>
  </context:component-scan>


  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
  <bean id="myAspect" class="com.myapp.annotation.MyAspect" />

    ...
```

**MyComponent.java:**

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
  @MyAnnotation(value="valtest", key="keytest", condition="contest")
  public int add(int i, int j) {
    System.out.println("Executing annotation.add");
    return i+j;
  }
}
```

Test code:

```
final MyComponent m = new MyComponent();
assertTrue(5 == m.add(0, 1)); // Here m.add(...) always returns 1 instead of 5.
```

As a side note I've tried to define my pointcut many different ways, all with and without the use of the anyPublic() method and its execution pointcut, but none of those worked for me:

1. `@Around("@annotation(com.myapp.annotation.MyAnnotation)")
   public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable { .. }`
2. `@Around(value="@annotation(myAnnotation)", argNames="myAnnotation") 
   public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable { .. }`
3. `@Around("execution(* com.myapp.*.*(..)) && @annotation(com.myapp.annotation.MyAnnotation)")
   public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable { .. }`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling `new`, unless you're specifically instrumenting bytecode to allow instantiation via `new`s instead of going through the app context, or weaving at compile time, the instantiated object is completely ignorant of anything Spring- or AOP-related.

Comment: Thanks Dave that was it! I can't believe I fell for that again. Sometimes we all need another pair of eyes to highlight the obvious.

Comment: This question/answer just helped us a ton!  Also, note that the 'myAnnotation' in @annotation(myAnnotation) really does start with lower case to match the parameter name in the declaration of process.  We spent a bunch of time looking at "formal parameter not specified" before noticing that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your test code, you are not allowing Spring to create your `MyComponent`, but instead, you are using the `new` operator.  You should be accessing `MyComponent` from Spring's `ApplicationContext`.

```
public class SomeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        final MyComponent myComponent = appContext.getBean(MyComponent.class);
        //your test here...
    }
}
```

If you do not get your component from Spring, how do you expect it to be proxied?